# Is it possible to select column based on previous column case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to group my customers into say 3 groups according on their postal ZIP code.

In the customer DB there is 2 fields that can contain the ZIP code.

Street Address Zip is primary and Postal Address is used if the user did not enter Zip for the street address.

Some times both are NULL and it is possible illegal values has been input.

So I first need to get the ZIP with a Case statement:

case 
when streetAddress.zip IS not NULL and streetAddress.zip between '0' and '99999' then streetAddress.zip
when postalAddress.zip IS not NULL and postalAddress.zip between '0' and '99999' then postalAddress.zip
else NULL end 
)'PostCode',

But now I want in the next column to select based on 'PostCode' but it seems it is not possible to use the value from previous column.

Somthing like
case 
when PostCode is between '00000' and '33333' then 'Zone1'
when PostCode is between '33334' and '66666' then 'Zone2'
when PostCode is between '66669' and '99999' then 'Zone3'
end

In the end I am trying to make a view that then would hold the PostCode and Zone value.

Comment: COALESCE(AddressZip, PostalZip) ?

Comment: Side note: you actually want to create a table (and maybe an associated, materialized view) to deal with your zip->zone range conversion.  This makes it trivial to update (no need to touch queries that do the conversion), and can even completely prevent certain types of configuration errors (ie, overlapping ranges).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a subquery?

```
select . . .
from (select c.*,
             (case when streetAddress.zip IS not NULL and streetAddress.zip between '0' and '99999'
                   then streetAddress.zip
                   when postalAddress.zip IS not NULL and postalAddress.zip between '0' and '99999'
                   then postalAddress.zip
                   else NULL
              end) as PostCode
      from . . .
     ) c
```

You can use the column `PostCode` in the outer `select`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat all the code from the first case if you want it in one query, but you could use a CTE to select all data with the first case and then everything from that and applying the second case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want everything in a single query try reusing the case statement and sql looks like below
or you can use SubQuery

```
select 
(case 
    when streetAddress.zip IS not NULL and streetAddress.zip between '0' and '99999' then streetAddress.zip 
    when streetAddress.zip IS NULL and postalAddress.zip IS not NULL and postalAddress.zip between '0' and '99999' then postalAddress.zip 
    else NULL 
 end ) AS [PostCode],
 (case 
    when streetAddress.zip IS not NULL and streetAddress.zip between '0' and '99999' then 
    <GroupA: Your Logic to get the column based on the value 'streetAddress.zip'>
    when streetAddress.zip IS NULL and postalAddress.zip IS not NULL and postalAddress.zip between '0' and '99999' then
    <GroupB: Your Logic to get the column based on the value 'postalAddress.zip'>
    else <GroupC:>
 end ) AS [PostCodeDependentColumn]
 From ....
```